# How to change the size of the text programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I use UITextView to display text to the user, this text contains titles and subtitles, I need to make the titles size bigger than the subtitles programmatically. How can I do that please?

Comment: I wanted to do the same thing and became fed up with it – I ended up using UIWebView. Would this work for you?

Comment: UITextView does not account for varying fonts/sizes - you will need to use separate views for such thing. Another option might be using something like Three20's styled labels/views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation for `UITextView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html):

> The font, color, and text alignment
>   attributes you specify always apply to
>   the entire contents of the text view.

If you want to have richer formatting capabilities, you may want to try `UIWebView`. Sadly, this will not have the editing capabilities of `UITextView`.

The other option is to overlay `UITextView`s with one another, but then alignment may become an issue. Those really are your two best options, though.

Comment: overlaying UITextViews could become a bit inefficient and dirty.  UIWebView will work, but you'll have to build up your HTML instead of regular strings.

Comment: Yes, but a `UIWebView` cannot be edited. If he really needs that functionality, then overlaying may achieve it. I agree, it won't be easy or pretty.

Answer (score 2):

UITextView is not a *rich text* editor.  This means that it does not have the ability to save different text attributes over various ranges of the text.  It is impossible to change this by any method.

NSAttributedString *does* have the ability to store rich text.  Also, you can draw NSAttributedStrings with core text.  If you don't need the text to be editable, just build yourself an appropriate NSAttributedString and let Core Text draw it (Core Graphics under the hood).

Good luck!

Edit: The drawing methods can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Note, this actually is a CocoaTouch question, hence no such thing like NSTextView available. Retagging it now...